# How to obfuscate background with css3?

Tags: css, background

I need to shade the background image.

```
background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(0,0,0,0.5), rgba(0,0,0,0.5)), url("background.png");
```

This code works OK, but is there a simpler way to do it?

Comment: A simpler of doing what? You haven't explained what you are trying to acheive

Comment: You can replace the `linear-gradient(...)` with `rgba(0,0,0,0.5)` since the gradient has same color for start and end.

Comment: @SalmanA, This is the reason I started this topic! It's not valid and it doesn't work.

Comment: @SalmanA The spec is : images for all the background-images, except the last, where a color is accepted

Answer (score 0):

Why use gradient ? 
Just set background like this :

```
background: url("background.png"), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
```

Depending of what you need, you could use box-shadow.

```
box-shadow: inset 0 0 100px black;
```

The only problem is that shadows will also come from the sides.

Comment: in first example the color is invisible if the image is not transparent.

Comment: You should not make your background-image transparent with CSS. Make it transparent with an image editor. If you want a full CSS solution, the only way is to use a pseudo element as in Mr. Dudak answer.

Comment: As @anton-tsyganenko says,the order here is important. In your first example, the rgba(0,0,0,0.5) is under the image, not above it.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a semitransparent pseudoelement covering the whole image:

```
.element {
    position: relative;
}

.element:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    pointer-events: none; /* if the element below needs to be clickable */
}
```

That's just one of the ways you can implement it. It'll render faster than a gradient but I'm not sure about simplicity of it ;)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use background images for making shadows. Its increase your site loading time gradually.

Best way for adding this css to your element:

```
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
```

I recommend this site for generating shadows: http://www.cssmatic.com/box-shadow

Comment: Yes @FC unprefixed support:89.86% of browser. but coming to cross browser comparability you have to use prefix for remaining '0.76%'. This not an wrong way right.